# Is there a way to make custom confetti animation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, mobile-application

First I want to tell you what to do and what is the problem?
I want to make confetti animation in my Flutter app and I know how to do it, but I want to make it custom [enter image description here][1]

bu i want this confetti animation [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejED9.jpg (As you can see here it has stars on it)

But I want this animation   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1U1P.png

I know that I need to make custom Path. but I don't know how to do that. Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this package [confetti](https://pub.dev/packages/confetti/example) could help? in their example, they have a method to paint custom confetti (it was stars which is similar to the image)

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent[200],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ConfettiWidget(
                confettiController: _confettiController,
                createParticlePath: drawCustomConfetti,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _confettiController.play,
                    child: Text("show confetti")),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _confettiController.stop,
                  child: Text("stop showing confetti"))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //here you can draw the custom confetti
  Path drawCustomConfetti(Size? size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(10, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 10);
    path.lineTo(-10, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, -10);
    path.lineTo(10, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
```

here is the code on how to use the [confetti](https://pub.dev/packages/confetti/example) package, and you can use the function to modify the shape using dart's Path.

[this is an article on how to use path in dart](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0)

you can also check the [confetti](https://pub.dev/packages/confetti/example) package for more details on how to change the speed, blast direction, etc

Comment: Yes I know but I want to know, how can i make kinda square animations not star

Comment: their default animation is a square confetti

Comment: sorry I don't mean square I meant this https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1U1P.png

Comment: @FatihKoc you need to use custom painter to draw that shape and give it to the ConfettiWidget